# Why does the ICU use this aliasing barrier when doing a reinterpret_cast?

Tags: icu, reinterpret-cast

I'm porting code from ICU 58.2 to ICU 59.1 where they changed the character type from a uint16_t to a char16_t. I was going to just do a straight reinterpret_cast where I needed to convert the types, but found that the ICU 59.1 actually provides functions for this conversion. What I don't understand is why they need to use this anti aliasing barrier before doing a reinterpret_cast.

```
#elif (defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)) && U_PLATFORM != 
U_PF_BROWSER_NATIVE_CLIENT
#   define U_ALIASING_BARRIER(ptr) asm volatile("" : : "rm"(ptr) : "memory")
#endif
```

...

```
    inline const UChar *toUCharPtr(const char16_t *p) {
#ifdef U_ALIASING_BARRIER
    U_ALIASING_BARRIER(p);
#endif
    return reinterpret_cast<const UChar *>(p);
```

Why wouldn't it be safe just to use reinterpret_cast without calling U_ALIASING_BARRIER?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a guess, it's to stop any violations of the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), that might occur in calling code that hasn't been completely cleaned up, from resulting in unexpected behaviour when optimizing (the hint to this is in the comment above: "Barrier for pointer anti-aliasing optimizations even across function boundaries.").

The strict aliasing rule forbids dereferencing pointers that alias the same value when they have incompatible types (a C notion, but C++ says a similar thing with more words). Here's a small gotcha: `char16_t` and `uint16_t` aren't required to be compatible. `uint16_t` is actually an optionally-supported type (in both C and C++); `char16_t` is equivalent to `uint_least16_t`, which isn't *necessarily* the same type. It will have the same width on x86, but a compiler isn't required to have it tagged as actually being the same thing. It might even be intentionally lax with assuming types that typically indicate different intent could alias.

There's a more complete explanation in the linked answer, but basically given code like this:

```
uint16_t buffer[] = ...

buffer[0] = u'a';
uint16_t * pc1 = buffer;

char16_t * pc2 = (char16_t *)pc1;
pc2[0] = u'b';

uint16_t c3 = pc1[0];
```

...if for whatever reason the compiler doesn't have `char16_t` and `uint16_t` tagged as compatible, and you're compiling with optimizations on including its equivalent of `-fstrict-aliasing`, it's allowed to assume that the write through `pc2` couldn't have modified whatever `pc1` points at, and not reload the value before assigning it to `c3`, possibly giving it `u'a'` instead.

Code a bit like the example could plausibly arise mid-way through a conversion process where the previous code was happily using `uint16_t *` everywhere, but now a `char16_t *` is made available at the top of a block for compatibility with ICU 59, before all the code below has been completely changed to read only through the correctly-typed pointer.

Since compilers don't generally optimize hand-coded assembly, the presence of an `asm` block will force it to check all of its assumptions about the state of registers and other temporary values, and do a full reload of every value the first time it's dereferenced after `U_ALIASING_BARRIER`, regardless of optimization flags. This won't protect you from any further aliasing problems if you continue to *write* through the `uint16_t *` below the conversion (if you do that, it's legitimately your own fault), but it should at least ensure the state from before the conversion call doesn't persist in a way that could cause writes through the new pointer to be accidentally skipped afterwards.

Comment: Well explained. That’s how I understand it myself. (icu team)